# Save a file where user wants, and in HTML or XML format only

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm developing a web application using asp.net. There is a text box which contains a HTML or XML file(loaded from server). After validating the file, I want to store that file where the user wishes to save(client), and the user must save in HTML or XML format only.
I had developed a code, but it automatically saves, without asking the user.

```
 protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string getnote = txtdisplay.Text.Trim();
        String filepath = Server.MapPath(@"img\new1.txt");
        System.IO.FileStream ab = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        System.IO.StreamWriter Write101 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ab);
        Write101.WriteLine(getnote);
        Write101.Close();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links might be helpful to  you .. Search for Save File Dialog(windows application) equivalent in asp.net/javascript.
Refer [How can I get the user response regarding SaveFileDialog in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286932/how-can-i-get-the-user-response-regarding-savefiledialog-in-javascript)
and
[Open File Dialog Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578946/open-file-dialog-asp-net)